# How to implement interval-based data modeling in power BI?

Tags: powerbi, dax, data-modeling, business-intelligence

My fact table looks like this:

| device_id | RAM | valid_from | valid_until |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10GB | 02.01.2020 | 01.01.2022 |
| 1 | 20GB | 01.01.2019 | 01.01.2020 |
| 2 | 15GB | 01.01.2019 | 15.06.2023 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

This is a simplified table with information about devices. It shows how much RAM a device had during a specific time interval.

By saving the data in this format, we save a lot of storage.

Now, I want to report on this data. What I want to achieve is to select a date in my calendar table and see, for instance, how much RAM did a specific device have on that date.

For example, if I filter for 25.04.2021, I would see device with id = 1 which has 10GB RAM.
Another example, I click on 25.04.2021 and want to count all devices that existed on this particular date.

I was first trying to model it in PowerBI. However, the problem is that there is no way to map a date to a range. To take my example from above, I cannot map 25.04.2021 to 02.01.2020-01.01.2022.

I know that it is possible to write SQL queries for this problem, but I am looking for some BI tool or data modeling approach in a BI tool that can deal with this kind of problems and visualize the results.

Do you know if there is a smart way to solve this problem in PowerBI?

I tried to create a measure using greater & less than, but without success.

Comment: The easiest way is to use another unrelated date table to filter from and to define the filter criteria with this unrelated “filter_date” in your measure e.g. valid_from <= filter_date && valid_until >= filter_date.  **Edit:** The key point is that this filter_date is **not connected** to your fact table

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you will need to have a relationship established between your fact table (device table) and the calendar table based on the date fields (valid_from and valid_until).

You may need to have a calculated column in the device table to determine whether the device was active on a specific date in the calendar table.

```
IsActive = IF(AND([valid_from] <= SELECTEDVALUE(Calendar[Date]), [valid_until] >= SELECTEDVALUE(Calendar[Date])), 1, 0)
```

When it comes to calculate the RAM for a specific date, you need a measure like below :

```
RAM On Selected Date = CALCULATE(MAX(device_table[RAM]), device_table[IsActive] = 1)
```

And for the count of devices on a specific date create another measure like below:

```
Device Count On Selected Date = CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(device_table), device_table[IsActive] = 1)
```