# Power Bi || Join Tables based on date range - one registration matched with multiple dates

Tags: powerbi

after search and questions to GPT, I came to the last resort....

I have table A

[image]

I have table B with columns

[image]

I want to join them if value of Weekending is between start and end, so I would have the following result

[image]

thanx!

Comment: Did you try with a search here as well? The comment there might be inspirational: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76494206/how-to-implement-interval-based-data-modeling-in-power-bi

Answer (score 0):

In Power Query you can cross-join tables by adding one table as a custom column on another table, then expanding the new column to rows.

Then just filter the cross-joined tables where WeekEnding is between start and end, eg:

```
let
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Actions, "Week", each Week),
    #"Expanded Week" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Added Custom", "Week", {"WeekEnding"}, {"WeekEnding"}),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Expanded Week", each [WeekEnding] >= [start] and [WeekEnding] < [end])
in
    #"Filtered Rows"
```